# Installing QGIS in Ubuntu

Tags: qgis-3, installation, ubuntu

I am trying to install the latest QGIS version (3.30.1 Hertogenbosch​) on my Ubuntu 20.04. I am following the instruction on the webpage (https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html#debian-ubuntu). The problem is when I do the QGIS repo (a document called qgis.sources located in /etc/apt/sources.list.d). My document qgis.sources is:

Types: deb deb-src
URIs: https://qgis.org/debian
Suites: fosa
Architectures: amd64
Components: main
Signed-By: /etc/apt/keyrings/qgis-archive-keyring.gpg

When I run the following command in the guide "sudo apt update" the following Error appears "E: The repository 'https://qgis.org/debian Fossa Release' does not have a Release file."

What is the cause and how do I solve it?

Comment: Please avoid using all-caps.

Comment: What is "Fossa" or "fosa"?

Comment: If you are using ALL-CAPS in the title to attract attention to your Question, please know that this is interpreted as SHOUTING, and generally results in downvoting and/or not reading your post (all-caps being harder to read). Please [Edit] your title.

Comment: Fossa is the casual name for Ubuntu 20.04 (Focal Fossa).

Answer (score 2):

For the suites listed above you have `fossa` but you want to use `focal` instead.
Still, it looks like you need to upgrade either your Ubuntu Version or the QT version.  See the image below from the [QGIS Ubuntu installation page](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html#debian-ubuntu).

[image]